# Unable to display emoji from unicode JSON response

Tags: javascript, html, json, unicode

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WeekAPI</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    Tag Value from Variable
    <h1 id="txtDisplay">Please Wait..</h1>

    Tag Value from API
    <h1 id="txtResponse">Please Wait..<h1>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        var tag_value = "\uD83D\uDE05\uD83D\uDE00\uD83D\uDE02\uD83D\uDE2C\uD83D\uDE10\uD83D\uDE0E";

        $("#txtDisplay").html(tag_value);


        var api = "http://week.esy.es/api?id=140393107018&institute=039&branch=07&semester=7&callback=?";

        $.getJSON(api, function(data) {
            //response tag value is same as tag_value variable
            $("#txtResponse").html(data.schedule.friday[0].tag);
        });   
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**API Response data**

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "message": "Successful.",
  "schedule": {
    "monday": [
      {
        "type": "lecture",
        "_id": 2,
        "start": "11:32 AM",
        "end": "11:32 AM",
        "teacher": "KPP",
        "subject": "Compiler Design",
        "tag": ""
      }
    ],
    "tuesday": [],
    "wednesday": [],
    "thursday": [],
    "friday": [
      {
        "type": "holiday",
        "_id": 2,
        "start": "09:30 AM",
        "end": "10:21 AM",
        "name": "\\u0928\\u0935\\u0930\\u093E\\u0924\\u094D\\u0930\\u093F",
        "tag": "\\uD83D\\uDE05\\uD83D\\uDE00\\uD83D\\uDE02\\uD83D\\uDE2C\\uD83D\\uDE10\\uD83D\\uDE0E"
      }
    ],
    "saturday": [],
    "sunday": []
  }
}
```

[image: WeekAPI output]

**1st scenario**

unicode value of emoji stored into `tag_value` variable

display using `$("#txtDisplay").html(tag_value);` in txtDisplay portion.

it **works fine**

but when

**2nd scenario**
retrieve tag value from api (value same as above)

display using `$("#txtResponse").html(data.schedule.friday[0].tag);` in txtResponse portion.

it is fails to display emoji. it is display text instead.

Comment: can you update the post with full json sample

Comment: post updated :)

Comment: The problem is at the server end, it is literally returning the string with letter ‘u’s and backslashes. Trying to unmangle it at the JS consumer is likely to be fragile (especially using the awful `eval`). This is better fixed at source.

Comment: i fixed problem at api server. you can check it in below answer and tell me if any change for improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the solution after understand internal work of javascript.

javascript interpret unicode only when unicode string hardcoded between quotes.

so i used `eval` function and created below code snippet to interpret unicode data runtime.

```
function interpret(s) {
    return eval("(function(){ return '" + s + "'})()");
}  

$.getJSON(api, function(data) {
    $("#txtResponse").html( interpret( data.schedule.friday[0].tag ) );
});
```

---

**Found another solution**

at server side just added `str_replace` function before printing response to replace \\ with \ in json

```
$response = json_encode($result);

echo str_replace( '\\\\' , '\\' , $response);
```

at client side

```
$.getJSON(api, function(data) {
    $("#txtResponse").html( data.schedule.friday[0].tag );
});
```

Comment: eval("(function(){ return '" + s + "'})()").... Thanks lot @asissithar. You save my day. +1 from me.